# How to pass arguments from one python script on the server to another?

Tags: python, argument-passing

I have 2 Python scripts on my server. I want to run the second one, **`SendMail.py`**, from **`MainScript.py`**, and I need to pass 2 arguments to it.

I want to call `send_mail` function in `MainScript.py`:

```
def send_mail(subject, body):
    # call SendMail.py with and pass the subject & body arguments
```

so it will run `SendMail.py`.

How can I run the other script while passing the arguments? Is it possible to do without importing the main function from `SendMail.py` into `MainScript.py`? How do I grab the arguments in `SendMail.py`?

Comment: You can't import `SendMail.py`?

Comment: I can, but I thought there must be a way to do this without importing it. Is that the best practice? If so, I'll go with that. I'm not quite sure how to use it either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `subprocess` module to run another python interpreter; `sys.executable` gives you a handy starting point:

```
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'SendMail.py', subject, body])
```

but best practice would be to just import `SendMail`; make sure you structure it to only run 'script-like' code with a `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard, then import the main 'sending' function from `SendMail` and re-use that:

```
def send_mail(subject, body):
    # main sending function


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # parse command line arguments into subject and body
    send_mail(subject, body)
```

then import `SendMail` and call `SendMail.send_mail(subject, body)`.

Comment: How do I use the arguments in `SendMail.py` in the first method? and how exactly do I import `SendMail.py` in the second method? thanks

Comment: @tempy: you can parse command line arguments in various ways; the `argparse` library that comes with Python is a good method.

Answer (score 1):

Use subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
args = [subject, body]
subprocess.call(['python','SendMail.py'] + args)
```

Inside `SendMail.py` use `sys.argv`:

```
import sys
subject, body = sys.argv[1:]
```

Comment: Yes, but why not create the *result* of the split in the first place? `.call()` takes an argument *list* when `shell=False`.

Comment: How do I grab the arguments in `SendMail.py`?